# Issue creating Azure App Registration with AZ CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I am trying to create an Azure AD app with an updated manifest that has access to Windows Azure AD. I have been able to successfully create / configure a new App Registration but run into issues when i try to configure the Manifest.

I have tried using the sample code provided my MS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create) with an updated 'resourceAppId' from an already existing App Registration however bash throws an error

```
az ad app create --display-name myTest --homepage https://blah.test.com --reply-urls https://blah.test.com/.auth/login/add/callback --required-resource-accesses @manifest.json("manifest.json" contains the following content)

[{"resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"resourceAccess": [
                    {
                     "id": "a42657d6-7f20-40e3-b6f0-cee03008a62a-test",
                     "type": "Scope"
                    }
                  ]
}]
```

As I've copied the sample code and just updated a few params i would expect it to run. TIA for any suggestions

This is the error i recieve when running via the portal

[image]

Comment: I see for `"id"` you have `-test` at the end of a GUID `a42657d6-7f20-40e3-b6f0-cee03008a62a-test`.. try replacing that with a new valid GUID only

Comment: i just stubbed that out for testing. I'm using a guid that i have copied from an existing app registrations manifest (that is set up correctly)

Comment: ok got it.. any more details about the error message you get back?

Comment: Could you provide the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you provide too little useful information, I am not sure what the error you got.

I have tested your script, and I got an error below.

```
az ad app create --display-name 'myTest' --homepage 'https://blah.test.com --reply-urls https://blah.test.com/.auth/login/add/callback' --required-resource-accesses 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\manifest.json'
az : ERROR: '--identifier-uris' is required for creating an application
    At line:1 char:1
    + az ad app create --display-name 'myTest' --homepage 'https://blah.tes ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: '--ident... an application:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

If you also get this error, just add the parameter like `--identifier-uris 'https://mytestapp.websites.net'`, the complete command will be like :

```
az ad app create --display-name 'myTest' --homepage 'https://blah.test.com' --reply-urls 'https://blah.test.com/.auth/login/add/callback' --identifier-uris 'https://mytestapp.websites.net' --required-resource-accesses 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\manifest.json'
```

Then it will work fine.

[image]

---

Per my understand, you may think some wrong with the `resourceAppId` in your `manifest.json`. If you do not get the error above, you could follow the information below to troubleshoot and make sure you use the correct properties in the `manifest.json`.

**My `manifest.json` file:**

```
   [{
      "resourceAppId": "69ae001f-xxxxxxxx-375585ac983e",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "6833b2c6-9954-43e1-ac46-f54a26a3b693",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
          "type": "Role"
        }
      ]
    }]
```

The `resourceAppId` is the application id of the service principal(i.e. the application id of the AD App), so you are correct.

In the `resourceAccess`, the `type` is `Scope` or `Role`. The `Scope` represents *Delegated permission*, `Role` represents *Application permission*. For the *Application permission*, you can find it in the `appRoles` in the manifest of the AD App which you are using(for my sample is the app `69ae001f-xxxxxxxx-375585ac983e`). For the *Delegated permission*, you can find it in the `oauth2Permissions` in the manifest. Then get the `id` in the corresponding position.

Check it along with my manifest of the sample AD App, note the `id` and correspondence, it will be clear.

**appRoles:**

```
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "displayName": "SurveyCreator",
      "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
      "value": "SurveyCreator"
    }
  ]
```

**oauth2Permissions:**

```
 "oauth2Permissions": [
    {
      "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access joywebtest on behalf of the signed-in user.",
      "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access joywebtest",
      "id": "6833b2c6-9954-43e1-ac46-f54a26a3b693",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "type": "User",
      "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access joywebtest on your behalf.",
      "userConsentDisplayName": "Access joywebtest",
      "value": "user_impersonation"
    }
  ]
```

At last, we could check the AD App which created just now in the portal. It will have the *Required permissions* we set.

[image]

For more details, you can also see [Azure Active Directory app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference).

Comment: i think splitting the json into a separate file was the trick