# App Registration - Expose an API - Authorized client applications - Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would liked to add client application in app registration. Is it possible with Azure CLI ? 
[image: Authorized Client Applications]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no such cli command to add client id in the "Authorized client applications".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the document to create an application with Azure [`CLI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create).

Also here is an example with the [`source code.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500388/issue-creating-azure-app-registration-with-az-cli)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I just want to add Client Id I know in the "Authorized client applications" section with PowerShell or CLI without being obliged to edit the manifest.json. Is it possible ?